# Чтение файла-устройства

Tags: c++, linux

Возникла задача прочитать файл-устройство. Делаю так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::fstream filestream;

    filestream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);
    filestream.open("/dev/sdc1",  std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);

    std::vector<char> vec(512);

    unsigned short size;
    while ((size = filestream.readsome(&vec[0], vec.size())))
    {
        // какие-то действия
    }

    filestream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Однако, этот код работает только при чтении обычных файлов. Когда я пытаюсь прочитать таким образом файл-устройство, то readsome возвращает 0.

При этом, используя метод read, я могу читать оба типа файлов. Однако этот метод не работает желаемым образом, если размер буфера указан больше, чем число прочитанных байт (я так понял, что возвращает null).

Как правильно реализовать задуманное?

**==================== UPDATE ====================**

Рабочий код на Си.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char key = 0xFF;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);

    if (fd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurs while openning %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char buffer[512];
    unsigned short n;

    while ((n = read(fd, buffer, 512)) > 0)
    {
        for (unsigned short i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            buffer[i] ^= key;

        lseek(fd, -n, SEEK_CUR);

        write(fd, buffer, n);
    }

    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: По крайней мере обычный системный вызов `read()` блоками по 4096 байт работает (только нужны рутовые права)

Comment: @avp если у меня файл 10 байт, то он даже не войдёт в цикл.

Comment: Вообще, вот прямо сейчас взял и проверил чтение /dev/sda1 в Linux  4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu. Читает и по 100 байт (без всяких пропусков), те же данные, что и при чтении блоками по 4096 (это меня немного удивило, просто помню были когда-то проблемы  с чтением не кратным блоку)

Comment: @avp Я проверял на обычном файле. Может ли быть в этом проблема? Просто создал обычный файл на 10 нулевых байт.

Comment: Не знаю. Я написал просто на Си  простым read (man 2 open; man 2 read). (впрочем, оттранслированная g++ программа работает так же)

Comment: **Как правильно реализовать задуманное?** - я как раз и не могу понять - а что Вы задумали? Зачем Вы пытаетесь читать УСТРОЙСТВО как ПОТОК ?! Вы понимаете, что устройство - это НЕ поток ?

Comment: @avp да, на Си у меня тоже работает. Странно было, почему на C++ такие проблемы возникли.

Comment: @Sergey ну, в общем да, понимаю. Устройство отмонтировано, с ним в общем-то не должно ничего произойти, поэтому могу читать как поток. Если о задуманном, то мне надо зашифровать его XOR-ом. Тот же код, написанный на С, как сделал avp, работает, и устройство нормально шифруется. Так что не вижу большой проблемы в чтении его как поток. А как вы бы сделали это?

Comment: Видимо [реализация](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/) уже стала слишком далека от того, что ожидает ОС при работе с блочным устройтвом. Из описания `.readsome()`  можно предположить, что эта функция скорее для символьных устройств.

Answer (score 2):

используйте метод basic_istream& std::basic_istream::get( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );

Comment: Как мне узнать, сколько байт я прочитал?

Comment: std::streamsize std::basic_istream::gcount() const;

Comment: спасибо. Сейчас возникают какие-то проблемы с записью в файл... Но это уже другой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, вопрос совсем не прост! Вспоминаем, что:

1. Файлы каталога /dev - псевдофайлы, обеспечивающие доступ к драйверу
2. Есть два основных типа драйверов: символьные и блочные.

Когда загружается драйвер **последовательного** (символьного) устройства, то он регистрирует в ядре список операций, которые этот драйвер может выполнять. Среди этих операций может быть операция ЧТЕНИЯ  (Поле .read в списке операций драйвера).

Для **блочных** устройств это не так. Вот цитата из библии "Драйверы устройств Linux", Третья редакция (Jonathan Corbet):

> Внимательные читатели, возможно, заметили интересное упущение из этого
>   списка: нет функций, которые фактически читают или записывают данные.
>   В блочной подсистеме ввода/вывода эти операции обрабатываются функцией
>   request, которая заслуживает своего собственного большого раздела и
>   будет рассмотрена далее в этой главе.

Проще говоря - когда вы пытаетесь читать с УСТРОЙСТВА /dev/sda, Вы получите нечто, не имеющие никакого отношения к содержимому диска / флэшки.

Ну а то, что ваша программа на чистом С, якобы, работала - у меня вызывает некоторые сомнения. Что значит РАБОТАЛА? Вы какими средствами смотрели нулевой сектор нулевой дорожки нулевого цилиндра ? Сравнивали с тем, что "видит" Ваша программа ? Сдаётся, мне что Вы просто НЕ проверяли код завершения, возвращаемый read(...).

Comment: Не не, я вырвал необходимый мне код из исходников TrueCrypt, удалив все их алгоритмы, добавив лишь свой XOR, и собрал драйвер на базе device-mapper, который шифрует и дешиврует данные на лету. И это действительно работает с устройствами, которые я кодировал своей прогой на Си. Над разделами системы не пробовал, но флешка читается и пишется. Код того, что я делаю на Си добавил в вопросе. Если интересен код драйвера, могу и его показать

Comment: Только что зашифровал таким образом отмонтированный root-раздел (через live-usb), и через этот драйвер он примонтировался.

Comment: **Если интересен код драйвера, могу и его показать** - не нужно.. С *device-mapper* я никогда не работал, так что - сказать нечего.

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за ответ!